# split a dynamic generated HTML files

Tags: c#

My application converts several types of documents into HTML files. Then, it exposes generated files to users or search engine robots.

My problem is that some documents contain more than 100 pages and the generated HTML file is huge.

I am looking for a way to split HTML files into several pages.

One possible solution is split them by size and number of characters which is a tough solution because we should consider the style of HTML files.

For example, consider following HTML file:

```
<p>

          -- So long paragraph with more than 100 lines 

</p>
<table>
  <tr>
        <td> </td>
  </tr>
  ...... more than 10 rows
</table>
```

the split mechanism should create several files for the paragraph and also, it should create one file for the table. like following:

### **PAGE1.HTML**

```
 <p>

           -- contains 20 lines of original text

 </p>
```

### **PAGE2.HTML**

```
 <p>

           -- contains 20 lines of original text

 </p>
```

### **PAGE3.HTML**

```
  <p>

       -- contains 20 lines of original text

     </p>
```

...

### **PAGE6.HTML**

```
 <p>

  <table>
     <tr>
        <td> </td>
     </tr>
     ...... more than 10 rows
</table>

</p>
```

please advice me, if you know a better solution or tools for achieving the solution?

Answer (score 0):

You have to disentangle content from the HTML. If you opt for an intermediate  format, that you control, you can generate HTML files with appropriate amount of content.

Trying to cut it after the HTML is generated is worse option, and inefficient one. You can try and navigate the HTML document using (e.g.) HtmlAgilityPack, but without intimate knowledge of what elements in what structure you actually generate it's hard to pinpoint the way of actually performing the split - and again, it will be much harder than splitting the content before it becomes HTML.

Comment: unfortunately, HTML files is generated by other application and I cannot modify it